# Fully-collapsed hierarchy in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

This is the Kendo UI demo showing hierarchical data: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy

It seems to work very well, but the first row is expanded automatically. I tried hacking around with it in their dojo, but couldn't find a way to disable that behavior.

How do I prevent rows from being automatically expanded in Kendo UI Grid?

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/AXiXE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there is used `expandRow` method in `dataBound` event to expand first row. Remove it.

```
var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ....
    dataBound: function() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    },
    ....
});
```

Comment: ...and the harder I looked for something like that, the more I missed it :)

Comment: Awesome. Should would be nice if Kendo (and everyone else) commented their examples a bit better. I've spent more than half and hour messing around trying to prevent this rather annoying behavior.